# What is the purpose of ng eject?

Tags: angular, command, angular-cli

The [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) is very brief with this topic:

> `ng eject` ejects your app and output the proper webpack configuration
>   and scripts

What is the purpose of this command?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

angular-cli is something magic, everything is done in a simple and automatic way.

But sometimes, you may want to act on how the package is done, add a plugin or you are simply curious to see the Webpack configuration on which it is based.

When running `ng eject`, you generate a `webpack.config.json` file. Looking at the file `package.json` you will see that the commands to launch have slightly changed:

```
ng serve --> npm start
ng build --> npm run build
ng e2e   --> npm run e2
```

---

If you want to **undo** `ng eject`, you will have to edit your `.angular.cli.json` file and set `ejected` to false:

```
"project": { 
  ...
  "ejected": false
}
```

Comment: But what does "undoing" that actually do? Those files will still exist, right?

Answer (score 10):

ng eject basically get-rid of angular cli scripts and introduce webpack scripts in package.json, underlying webpack.config.js file mainly for comprehensive way to manage the project and it will be completely our responsibility to manage the project configurations after this.

A comparison of package.json scripts before and after is below,
[image]

check https://medium.jonasbandi.net/to-use-angular-cli-or-not-187f87d0b550 for further read.