# angular cli build without bundling

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Running ng build for a new angular project compiles to build files. This is inconvenient as I want to access the files directly without bundling after the angular project has been built for easy editing. Is there any way to build an angular project without bundling and just keeping the original typescript and html files after the build?

Comment: The original typescript and html files are not destroyed by ng build. They're left there in your src directory. Use `ng serve` or `ng build --watch`, edit the source files, and the cli will rebuild automatically.

Comment: Use bundling and source maps. Or you can eject the CLI project and take control of your builds.

Comment: @BrandonSørenCulley what do you mean eject the CLI project ?

Comment: @JesonMartajaya ng-cli uses webpack under the hood. It provides `eject` option to spit out the webpack config file (and ng-cli is no more the build system for your module). Once done, you will have complete power to customize the build any way you want with webpack.

Comment: Fyi, I created a ng-cli issue in github here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10811

Comment: @JesonMartajaya You can eject an angular cli project and take control of the build process and customize it to your specifications, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110064/what-is-the-purpose-of-ng-eject#44110463

Comment: @BrandonSørenCulley I see, `eject` may allow me to override `angular-cli` file. What is the Webpack setting to prevent bundling ?

Answer (score 1):

ng cli (or webpack or any other js bundler) is there to bundle your source code into browser-compatible code.

That is because Typescript (guess thats the case here) can not be understood by all browsers **as-is**. So, you need to use a bundler to transform it to javascript.

ng-cli (or webpack for that matter) does provide a way to keep it running and watch over your source files. This is same as what you are asking for but with one difference : ng-cli (or webpack) does the incremental bundling whenever you modify your source code.

As pointed out in other comments, you can have a look at ng-cli and give it a try.

Comment: Is there a parameter that keeps typescript transpiled at their original source directory ?